# Homework Problem, Implicit Function Theorem

Tags: multivariable-calculus, implicit-function-theorem

Given the following equation:

$$
x^3y -y^3x -6 = 0 
$$

determine using implicit differentiation $y'(2)$. (exact wording) Where $y' = \frac{\partial y}{\partial x}$

I called

$$
f(x,y) = x^3y -y^3x -6 = 0
$$
Here is what I have done so far:

$$
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(f(x,y)) &= 3x^2y - y^3 \\
\frac{\partial}{\partial y}(f(x,y)) &= x^3 - 3y^2x \\
f'(x) &= -\frac{\frac{\partial}{\partial x} (f(x,y))}{\frac{\partial}{\partial y} (f(x,y))} = \frac{y^3- 3x^2y}{x^3 - 3y^2x}
\end{align*} 
$$

Here I am stuck because I cannot express y as a function of x:

$$
x^3y -y^3x -6 = 0 \\
$$

or at least i do not see a way. Without expressing $y = g(x)$ I can not solve $f'(x)$. Am i missing something here?

Comment: I think the question is ill posed: what does $y'(2)$ mean? There are three points satisfying the equation $f(x,y)=0$ with $x=2$.

Comment: I agree, made an edit with the the exact wording.

Comment: First, do not write $f'(x)$ for $g'(x)$. Next, the most important thing is that you're off by a negative sign. You should have $$g'(x) = -\dfrac{\partial f/\partial x}{\partial f/\partial y}.$$ (Why?)

Comment: you are right! I missed the "-".Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $x=2$ we obtain:
$$8y-2y^3-6=0$$ or
$$y^3-4y+3=0$$ or
$$y^3-y^2+y^2-y-3y+3=0$$ 0r
$$(y-1)(y^2+y-3)=0,$$ which gives three points.

Can you end it now?

Also, I got $$y'=\frac{y^3-3x^2y}{x^3-3xy^2}.$$

Comment: I don't think so. So there is y_1 = 1, y_2 = -3/2, y_3 = -1/2 satisfying f(2, y_i) = 0. Sry, I don't know what to do with this information. No, i really don't get it.

Comment: @user2550228 I don't agree. The point $(2,-1.5)$ is not placed there. Check it again. The same words we can say about $(2,-0.5).$

Comment: (-1 +- sqrt(13))/2? Sry for the mistakes, i really am. I am having a really hard time with this topic.

Comment: @user2550228 Yes, and to substitute.

Comment: But then i get three different derivatives.

Comment: @user2550228 Because they are three different points.

Comment: aaaaaah, okay. I think i'm  getting there now. Thanks for the help, really appreciate it.

Comment: @user2550228 You are welcome!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109085/discussion-between-user2550228-and-michael-rozenberg).